# Sublime Text can't fuzzy search after "bundle open gem_name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3

Ruby gives you an easy way to view the contents of a dependency library with

```
$ bundle open gem_name
```

When I do this, it opens in Sublime Text but fuzzy text and file searches don't work. How can I configure ST to search folders that are open with `bundle open`?

Screenshot example:

[image]

Settings:

```
{
  "CucumberStepFinder":
  {
    "open_in_different_pane": false
  },
  "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
  "auto_find_in_selection": true,
  "binary_file_patterns":
  [
    "*.beam",
    "node_modules",
    "assets/javascripts/*-bundle.js",
    "*.gif",
    "*.jpg",
    "*.ttf",
    "*.tga",
    "*.dds",
    "*.ico",
    "*.eot",
    "*.pdf",
    "*.png",
    "*.swf",
    "*.jar",
    "*.zip",
    "*.svg",
    "*.eps",
    "*.pack",
    "*.log"
  ],
  "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
  "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
  "font_size": 17,
  "hot_exit": false,
  "ignored_packages":
  [
    "Vintage"
  ],
  "match_brackets": false,
  "remember_open_files": false,
  "show_errors_inline": false,
  "tab_size": 2,
  "trailing_spaces_modified_lines_only": true,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: `Find in Files` implicitly searches in Open files and Folders unless you specify something specific in the `Where:` field to override it. As long as whatever that command does tells Sublime to open the folder the bundle is in, it should work just fine as @maxpleaner says.

Comment: @OdatNurd no dice. That also doesn't explain why file searching doesn't work for me. I've added a screenshot with further information. Seems like I must have a setting different than others do.

Comment: @maxpleaner seems like I must have a setting different then. I've added a screenshot showing that it is not working for me for text search. File searching also does not work.

Comment: What does your `binary_file_patterns` setting look like?

Comment: @OdatNurd added settings.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any reason that wouldn't work, unfortunately; or at least I can't replicate it with the same settings.